# BAT Using for /f on a text file not working?

Tags: batch-file, windows-shell

I am trying to use the for /F to feed in 3 variables and use them to move files into the folders they need to be in for organization.

The script is doing exactly what I want it to do... EXCEPT it is only doing it for the very last line in the .txt file.  I thought the /F would automatically do the command for each line in the text file but something is wrong and it is not.

Can anyone tell me how to fix the below code so it will work for every line in the text instead of just the last line?

Thank you!

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%G in (MoveFiles.txt) do (
@set "Account_ID=%%G" 
@set "PACKAGE_ID=%%H" 
@set "FILE_NAME=%%I")

mkdir -p "O:\Documents and Media\%PACKAGE_ID%\%ACCOUNT_ID%"

SET FOO="O:\MediaAttachments\%FILE_NAME%"
COPY %FOO% "O:\Documents and Media\%PACKAGE_ID%\%ACCOUNT_ID%\%FILE_NAME%"
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything that you want done on every line must be done IN the for loop.

What's happening is that you're updating your variables for each line.  So, they are on the last set items when they come out of the for loop.  Then you do your mkdir, set, & copy which is only for that last item.

Moving the end parenthesis to the bottom should fix only doing things once.

Then change `%` to `!` to use the `EnableDelayedExpansion` that you've already set up.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%G in (MoveFiles.txt) do (
    @set "Account_ID=%%G" 
    @set "PACKAGE_ID=%%H" 
    @set "FILE_NAME=%%I"

    mkdir -p "O:\Documents and Media\!PACKAGE_ID!\!ACCOUNT_ID!"

    SET FOO="O:\MediaAttachments\!FILE_NAME!"
    COPY !FOO! "O:\Documents and Media\!PACKAGE_ID!\!ACCOUNT_ID!\!FILE_NAME!"
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding so quickly. That makes perfect sense!

Unfortunately when I moved the parenthesis to the bottom the script stopped doing what I thought it should.  It appears to not be setting the variables at all and instead is copying everything from O:\Documents and Media\\\filename.pdf into the local directory that I am running the script from.

I can't pinpoint why this is happening- either the lack of setting variables or the ignoring of the intended source and using the destination as the source.

Comment: Your second problem is because you are using % instead of !, causing the variables to be evaluated too soon.

Comment: I have never seen a ! used for a variable in a batch script. Would this be a change through the entire script or only when calling the variables in the mkdir and copy? What is the syntax for that? !Package_ID  ?

Comment: It's like the percent expansion, but it has to be enabled first with setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion. It's evaluated at execution (percent expansion is evaluated at parse time). And the expanded content isn't parse any more, so any content can be handled

Comment: @meshell: Yes, it's `!Package_ID!` instead of `%Package_ID%`. And if the succinct (but correct) explanation by @jeb is not enough for you, you could try a more elaborate one by issuing `SET /?` or `HELP SET` at the command prompt.

Comment: @meshell: Also you could try [searching Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+delayed+expansion&submit=search) for similar questions to see (and possibly be relieved by the fact) that you are not alone who have come across a situation like this. Some of the answers might also explain the issue the way you can understand it best.

Comment: I've added the switch of the `%` to `!` per the additional comments. Thanks! Please, remember to accept the answer if it solves your question.